# Distinguishing $n$ pure states in an $n$ dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: measurement, probability, projection-operator, povm, state-discrimination

Suppose we have $n$ pure states in an $n$ dimensional Hilbert space, and we would like to distinguish them using POVM or PVM. We get any one of the pure states with equal probability, and we may set the metric to be the average or the worst-case success probability.

Are there examples where POVM can do better than projective measurement (or a known proof it does not)?

Comment: In finite dimensions, anything a POVM can do, there is a PVM with the same outcome probabilities via a Naimark dilation.

Comment: But this PVM will be in a larger space? Can we still have a PVM that is as good as the POVM in this $n$ dimensional space?

Comment: You are correct, the dilation gives a projection in a larger space.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "we would like to distinguish them"

Comment: @Dani007 probably to find the POVM that optimally discriminates between the elements of the ensemble. In other words, the POVM $\mu$ that maximises the quantity $\sum_a \langle\mu_a,\rho_a\rangle$ with $\rho_a$ elements of the ensemble (assumed to be equiprobable). Or in this case, whether the optimal such POVM is (or at least can be chosen to be) a PVM, when there's $n$ different $\rho_a$ each of which is pure.

Comment: I'm tempted to say such an example might be a set of three qutrit states that only span a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$. Say, 3 qubit states symmetrically distributed in the Bloch sphere, embedded in $\mathbb{C}^3$. I think such an ensemble of 3 qubit states is optimally discriminated using a SIC-POVM when you work in $\mathbb{C}^2$. The question is whether this can become a PVM in $\mathbb{C}^3$, but that doesn't seem likely to me. I don't have a formal argument though. Chapter 2 of ([Bae and Kwek 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.02571)) might be useful here

Comment: Consider the regular $n$-simplex formed by connecting $\{|i\rangle\}_{i\in[n]}$, it lies in an $n-1$ dimensional subspace. Now, take vectors from the centre of the the regular $n$-simplex to the vertices (i.e. $[(n-1)/n, -1/n, -1/n, \cdots, -1/n]^T, \cdots$), subject to proper normalization. There should be a uniform transformation that maps from the states you said to the above states, and the set of projectors $\{|i\rangle\langle i|\}_{i\in[n]}$ optimally distinguishes them.

Comment: related on physicsç https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/714797/58382

Comment: I don't know that I understand your example. For $n=2$ I think you're referring to the states $|0\rangle$, $|+\rangle$, and $|+i\rangle\equiv|0\rangle+i |1\rangle$, correct? What is a "uniform transformation" sending $|0\rangle,|1\rangle,|0\rangle+|1\rangle$ to those states?

Comment: @glS See if this is correct: Your example had $|0\rangle$, $\cos(2\pi/3)|0\rangle + \sin(2\pi/3)|1\rangle$ and $\cos(4\pi/3)|0\rangle + \sin(4\pi/3)|1\rangle$. They span a two dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$. We can transform it to $\sqrt{2/3}|0\rangle- \sqrt{1/6}|1\rangle-\sqrt{1/6}|2\rangle$, $-\sqrt{1/6}|0\rangle+ \sqrt{2/3}|1\rangle-\sqrt{1/6}|2\rangle$ and $-\sqrt{1/6}|0\rangle- \sqrt{1/6}|1\rangle+\sqrt{2/3}|2\rangle$. If we do PVM in the basis $|0\rangle, |1\rangle, |2\rangle$, it should be optimal with success probability $2/3$.